# jquery ajax form submission issue - form data is submitted but returns error not success

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**Update**

*From Fiddler 2:*

I can see data sent.  Also they show up in the other site's database.

The response from the other domain/server seems incorrect:

```
Response sent 38 bytes of Cookie data:
Set-Cookie: ARPT=YOLMQLS172.25.102.96CKMYK; path=/

This response did not contain a P3P Header.
```

Is it safe to proceed with this implementation even though the header response is incorrect?

I am using the [jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate my form then jquery ajax to post the form data into an external website ([Marketo](http://www.marketo.com/) lead generation platform).

The form data is successfully submitted to the external site (Marketo). I verified this by logging into their website and I can see the test form posts I submitted with all the field data.

However, **I get an error and not a success response from the ajax call**.

Here is the code - any ideas?

```
$(feedbackForm).validate(
{
    validClass: "success",
    rules: 
    {
        FirstName: { required: true },
        LastName:  { required: true },
        Email:
        {
            required: true,
            email: true                                 
        },
        Question__c: { required: true }
    },
    messages:
    {
        FirstName: "Please enter your first name",
        LastName: "Please enter your last name",
        Email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        Question__c: "Please enter your message"
    },       
    submitHandler: function(form) 
    {            
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST", 
            url: "http://app-k.marketo.com/index.php/leadCapture/save",                
            data: feedbackForm.serialize(),
            success: function(response)
            {
                feedbackForm.find('.form_result').html(response.statusText);
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(response)
            {
                feedbackForm.find('.form_result').html(response.statusText);                       
                alert("error");
            }
        });  
        return false;          
    }
```

Comment: What does http://app-k.marketo.com/index.php/leadCapture/save return? In the 'error' function if you console.log(response) - What does that return? If you're returning a JSON array, you could just need to pass dataType: 'json' in your AJAX function.

Comment: Alert `$('#easycopyFeedbackForm').serialize()` and see what pops up

Comment: the console.log(response) returns a bunch of stuff, like statusText="error". I am not sure how to tell from the object if its returning json, but I tried dataType: 'json" and still same.

Comment: @Norse $('#easycopyFeedbackForm').serialize() returns all the form fields + data.

Comment: A great way to debug stuff like this is to fire it up in FireFox or Chrome and use the FireBug net panel or Chrome Developer tools Network tab respectively.  Here you will be able to see the data that was sent by your code and the exact response back from the server.  There is of course also Microsoft Fiddler2 which does the same thing but isn't integrated with the browser, so not as slick!

Comment: @Shawson just tested with fiddler actually :)  the data sent looks fine. The response does not.  Here is what I get:
Response sent 38 bytes of Cookie data:
Set-Cookie: ARPT=YOLMQLS172.25.102.96CKMYK; path=/

This response did not contain a P3P Header.

Comment: @RabNawazKhan same results with jsonp

Comment: @Shawson - so looks like the other domain is getting the data (i can see them), but it's responding with the correct headers or something. Is it safe to just keep the implementation as is (I don't care about the response being incorrect), or are there any issues with this approach?

Comment: Yeah Fiddler :) - no, not IE, Chrome & Firefox, but it's a mvc3 .net site so we use Fiddler.  no iframe or anything weird. however the site is on a dev server that's inside company walls, that make a difference?

Comment: I think the js looks fine, except for the cross domain issue- you could maybe use jsonp to get around that, if you have control of the server side component?  Failing that create a simple web service (or maybe a simple Action on your controller which returns a JsonResult) in your local app that you post to (so on the same domain), and then that service (/or action) posts from the server side and just relays back the response- this is a technique I often use, and I find easier than faffing around with jsonp callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be making an ajax request to a url that is not in your own domain, which is typically restricted due to cross-domain access restrictions.

if it is in fact not on your domain, you need to make the request to that server via server side language. the ajax call would be to the code that in turn makes that other call.

However, if they have allowed public access to that URL from outside domains, then what I said is irrelevant.

Comment: Kristian, the url is not on my domain, yes, so maybe you're in the right area. i'm on a .net application so would need to figure out how to make the call sever side.

Comment: But also wondering, if this was true, how come it's posting the data to the external site? Or it's the response message that does not come back due to cross-domain issue?

Comment: there is the distinct possibility that they are using that URL for a public API and that cross domain requests are allowed to that URL. it just depends on them